# Normal derivative of normal unit vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, vector-fields, riemann-surfaces

Let's say we have a curvilinear coordinate system $(\rho,\theta,\zeta)$. Also, let's say we have a surface $\Gamma$ parameterized as $\Gamma: \mathbf{S}(\rho(\theta,\zeta),\theta,\zeta) = \mathbf{S}(\theta,\zeta)$. I want to find the normal derivative $\partial_n$ of the normal unit vector $\mathbf{n}$ to the surface $\Gamma$. For this, let's use the following
identity:
$\nabla (\mathbf{A \cdot B}) = (\mathbf{A} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{B}  + (\mathbf{B} \cdot \nabla ) \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{A} \times( \nabla \times \mathbf{B})  + \mathbf{B} \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{A})\\$. Let $\mathbf{A=B=n}$ to obtain the following:

$\nabla (\mathbf{n \cdot n}) = (\mathbf{n} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{n}  + (\mathbf{n} \cdot \nabla ) \mathbf{n} + \mathbf{n} \times( \nabla \times \mathbf{n})  + \mathbf{n} \times (\nabla \times \mathbf{n})$

$\rightarrow \quad 0 = 2\frac{\partial}{\partial n}\mathbf{n}  + \mathbf{n} \times 0  + \mathbf{n} \times 0 $

$\rightarrow \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial n}\mathbf{n} = 0 $

The property $\nabla \times \mathbf{n}$ was applied to obtain the previous result. Now, in curvilinear coordinates, we have that $\partial_n = (\mathbf{n}\cdot \nabla) = (\mathbf{n}\cdot e^\rho)\partial_\rho + (\mathbf{n}\cdot e^\theta)\partial_\theta + (\mathbf{n}\cdot e^\zeta)\partial_\zeta$

Now, since the surface is parameterized as a function of $\theta,\zeta$, the normal vector at the surface of interest (which is our surface $\Gamma$) is simply defined as $\mathbf{n} = \frac{\partial_\theta \mathbf{S} \times \partial_\theta \mathbf{S}}{|\partial_\theta \mathbf{S} \times \partial_\theta \mathbf{S}|}$.

When evaluating $\partial_n \mathbf{n} = (\mathbf{n}\cdot e^\rho)\partial_\rho \mathbf{n} + (\mathbf{n}\cdot e^\theta)\partial_\theta \mathbf{n} + (\mathbf{n}\cdot e^\zeta)\partial_\zeta \mathbf{n}$

Should we completely ignore the term: $(\mathbf{n}\cdot e^\rho)\partial_\rho \mathbf{n} $ and set it to zero? In other words, is $(\mathbf{n}\cdot e^\rho)\partial_\rho \mathbf{n} = 0$ for any surface?

I have a surface parameterization and I am evaluating $(\mathbf{n}\cdot e^\theta)\partial_\theta \mathbf{n} + (\mathbf{n}\cdot e^\zeta)\partial_\zeta \mathbf{n}$ numerically but I am not getting exactly zero as the result. I was wondering if even though we know $\mathbf{n}$ on $\Gamma$, that does not mean that the vector $\mathbf{n}$ could not be a continuous vector in space that has derivatives in all directions?

I don't know if this makes sense. Any help  would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For starters, you cannot take the normal derivative of a (vector) function defined only on the surface. The normal derivative asks how the function changes as you move orthogonally off the surface.